# How to rearrange for b when dA/db = 0

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I am working out the optimum area of an ellipse which has an area of $$ \frac {ab\pi}2 $$

[Ellipse Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCSR0.jpg)

I found the perimeter ($p$) using Ramanujan's rule and rearranged and subbed in $a$ so now my area equation is:

$$A=\frac12\frac{3p+\sqrt{3p^2+12\pi pb-20\pi ^2 b^2}-4\pi b}{6\pi}b\pi$$

Note: from Ramanujan's Approximation; $$p≈\pi[3(a+b)-\sqrt{(3a+b)(a+3b)} ]$$

> How to find $b$, when $A'=0$, whilst keeping a generalized (not fixed) perimeter?

Such that $b=...p$

I should be able to then show that $b=a$ for the optimum area which is a semicircle, by subbing in the equation for $b$

Comment: should we compute the derivative with respect to$b$?

Comment: yes ok i have found the answer

Comment: Ow awesome! Please let me know :)